# Oracle JDev : ctrl+minus shortcut

Tags: shortcut, jdeveloper

In JDeveloper, ctrl+- is used to browse in application. It was working fine (was browsing only inside my application). Suddenly, it started pulling other projects, which are not even inside my source code. Is there anyway to configure this project files for this?

I use Oracle Jdev 10.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the below in my jpr file and removed this.

```
    <hash>
       <list n="classPath">
          <url path="../../../"/>
       </list>
       <value n="deployedByDefault" v="true"/>
       <value n="description" v="Main"/>
       <value n="id" v="Main"/>
       <value n="locked" v="true"/>
    </hash>
```